# Assistance with SQL update

Tags: sql, mysqli, sql-update

I hope that I'm making sense with this, but here goes.

What I want to do is take information from two tables (via a JOIN), and then UPDATE the information from those two tables into a third table.  Here is some test code that I wrote that will mimic almost exactly what I need to do.

My only problem, is that at the "SELECT * FROM @tempTable" at the end...I'm unsure of how to get an UPDATE to work on the userName and badgeId columns within the @tempTable table.  Everything I've tried just ends up inserting it into it's own row, as if I were doing an INSERT...

Any help is appreciated.  I wrote and ran the code in MS SQL Server 2008 R2, so it should work.

```
/* Create the 'Users' table */

DECLARE @Users TABLE(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    userName varchar(100),
    UserId int)

INSERT INTO @Users (userName, UserId)
VALUES ('jim', 100), 
       ('kira', 200),
       ('ken', 300),
       ('dan', 400),
       ('len', 500)

/* Create the 'Badges' table */
DECLARE @Badges TABLE(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    badgeId varchar(100),
    userId int)

INSERT INTO @Badges (badgeId, UserId)
VALUES (10, 100), 
       (20, 200),
       (30, 300),
       (40, 400),
       (50, 500)

/* Create the '@tempTable' */   
DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    userName varchar(100),
    badgeId int,
    divNumber int,
    secNumber int)  

INSERT INTO @tempTable (badgeId, userName, divNumber, secNumber)
VALUES (null, null, 68, 34),
       (null, null, 68, 34),
       (null, null, 69, 24),
       (null, null, 69, 24),
       (null, null, 70, 14)

/* Select userNames and badgeIds from the 'Users' and 'Badges' tables */    
SELECT u.userName, b.badgeId
FROM @Users as u
    INNER JOIN @Badges as b
    ON b.userId = u.UserId

/* Select all information from the '@tempTable' table */
SELECT * FROM @tempTable
```

[image]

Comment: Besides the fact that you should format the question better, what database are you using?  You have labelled it "mysqli".  But the syntax looks like SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking right try using this update statement at the end.

```
update @tempTable
set userName =  u.userName, 
badgeId = b.badgeId
FROM @Users as u
INNER JOIN @Badges as b
ON b.userId = u.UserId
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for the help!  Worked like a charm.  I think my problem was that I was joining on "ON userName = null".  Cheers!

Comment: Yup, just had to wait the 5 minute period before it would let me mark as answer.  Thanks again ;-)

Comment: Sorry to be impatient, I'm kind of new here